# The Number Puzzle

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Given the following four patterns:

1. ```
     12   34   8  -> 18
   ```
2. ```
    344   21  65  -> 21
   ```
3. ```
    234  345   1  -> 39
   ```
4. ```
   6734    1   8  -> 80
   ```

Then:

```
       1    3   5  -> ??
```

Comment: Is the [number-sequence] tag really appropriate? Given the `->` sign and that there are no commas between values it looks like e.g.`12   34   8` is the input (maybe random) and `18` is the output (some kind of operation involving the 3 input numbers return this result)

Comment: 1+2 + 3+4 + 8 = 18  that's all I got so far...

Comment: I am afraid, this isn't a good puzzle. Nothing in your question suggests what to do other than "guess what it can be". Even after a few days of no one solving it, you didn't provide any hints as to how to continue. It would have been better if you had subtly hinted at the number of digits part. Anything that would have kept the puzzler's interest would have been fine. But unfortunately, Nothing of that sort was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer.

First sequence:

> $12+34+8=54$ (2 digits)
>
>  $(5+4)\times 2=18$

Second sequence:

> $344+21+65=430$ (3 digits)
>
>  $(4+3+0)\times 3=21$

Third sequence:

> $234+345+1=580$ (3 digits)
>
>  $(5+8+0)\times 3=39$

Fourth sequence:

> $6734+1+8=6743$ (4 digits)
>
>  $(6+7+4+3)\times4=40$

So... the answer will be:

> $1+3+5=9$ (1 digit)
>
>  $9\times1=9$

Please give me some feedback so that I don't repeat any mistakes.

Comment: This answer makes it a good puzzle. Did not downvoted it but I guess the number sequence puzzles are mostly follow the same path. Added my +1 to both Q & A.

Comment: *Feedback.* There's nothing particularly interesting about this method of solution, nor is there anything in the question to clue solvers towards this rather than any other algorithm. The solution is also quite complicated, so it'd be hard for anyone to come up with the right idea without any prior hints. The only way to solve it would be by guessing randomly and getting lucky.

Comment: Puzzles that are literally nothing more than "Guess the *<foo>* I'm thinking of" are not puzzles, nor even riddles, they are blind search guessing games.  That applies whether the *<foo>* is a word, a number, a sequence, a function or algorithm, or a concrete thing.  A good puzzle contains clues that provide a path to a solution, or *at bare minimum* provide some context that greatly constrains the scope of any guessing required.